# How to print the summary of a variable in R shiny?

Tags: r, variables, printing, shiny, summary

I would like that based on a `selectInput()` which the client can select, the summary of the selected variable will be print in a box. My code for the ui.R is:

```
box(
  title = "Informed Investor", 
  status = "primary", 
  solidHeader = TRUE,
  width = 6,
  selectInput("informedDset", label="Select Category", choices = list("Informed Full" = "InformedFull", "Informed Fact" = "InformedFact", "Informed Fact Positive" = "InformedFact.Pos", "Informed Fact Negative" = "InformedFact.Neg", "Informed Emotions" = "InformedEmotions", "Informed Emotions Fact" = "InformedEmotionsFact"), selected = "Informed Full")
), 

box(
  title = "Data Table", 
  status = "warning", 
  solidHeader = TRUE,
  width = 6,
  height = 142,
  verbatimTextOutput("summaryDset")
)
```

And my code for server.R:

```
output$summaryDset <- renderPrint({
   summary(input$informedDset)
})
```

Comment: choices are just representation and should be used to retrieve a part of the data set, hence is not meaningful to summarize them. Check [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/selectInput.html) for more details.

Comment: What kind of summary? And why does your approach not work? What's going wrong?

Comment: @A.Suliman thanks! But do you know how can I solve my problem?

Comment: @phalteman Iam getting this:   `Length     Class      Mode 
        1 character character`

Comment: "InformedFull", .... etc should represent data or variable that can be summarized. As these are just names, try `summary("InformedFull")` in R.

Comment: Use [input$informedDataset]] as it contains text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, `summary` returns `Length Class Mode 1 character character` because the `input$informedDset` is a character string. 
If you want to extract the summary of one selected variable in a dataset you can find an reproducible example below with the `iris` dataset :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui=fluidPage(

 box(title = "Informed Investor", 
  status = "primary", 
  solidHeader = TRUE,
  width = 6,
  selectInput("informedDset", label="Select Category",
          choices = list("Sepal.Length"="Sepal.Length",
                         "Sepal.Width"="Sepal.Width",
                         "Petal.Length"="Petal.Length",
                         "Petal.Width"="Petal.Width",
                         "Species"="Species"), selected = "Sepal.Length")),

box(
 title = "Data Table", 
 status = "warning", 
 solidHeader = TRUE,
 width = 6,
 height = 142,
 verbatimTextOutput("summaryDset")))


server = function (input,output){
 output$summaryDset <- renderPrint({
 summary(iris[[input$informedDset]]) 
})}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Is that what you want to do ?

Comment: Aurelien your such a genius! thank your bro thats exactly I was searching for!!